# How is an IP address "part" called?

Tags: networking, operating-system, terminology

When validating an IP address, what is the correct name of each dot seperated "part".

For example, if a user inputs the following invalid IP:

```
999.45.34.23
```

What is the correct validation error message?

Is it: "The first IP octet is invalid" ?

References: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address)

Comment: Note that it's *octet*, not *octect*.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the typo (octet)

Comment: I would simply say "IP address is invalid" and let the user figure out the rest. That approach would also be compatible with IPv6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should stick with the technically correct term, which is **[octet](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/question549.htm)**.

The drawback, as others have observed, this has the potential to confuse typical users, who might have no idea what an "octet" is. Using a different term isn't a good option either, though, because you're likely to confuse and/or disappoint users who *do* know what an octet is and expected to see the correct term used in the appropriate context.

**Perhaps the best compromise is daring to go beyond the typical "Error: Invalid input" style message.** I would include a specific *example* of the input that was incorrect, along with the error text. In this case, you might show the IP address that the user entered, with the incorrect octet highlighted in red.

It requires a considerably greater amount of effort on the part of the programmer, who can no longer throw in a call to the `MessageBox` function and leave it at that. But there's a huge gain in usability. The advantage of this approach is that an experienced user can simply read the textual message and know exactly what needs to be fixed. An inexperienced user who doesn't understand the error can spend more time reading the dialog and *still* know exactly what needs to be fixed.

Consider the following concept sketch:

[image: More descriptive error message, with the problematic octet highlighted in red]

(Obviously, you'll need to modify accordingly when your application *finally* decides to support IPv6.)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply call it **part**. So in your case:

```
"The first part of your IP address is invalid."
```

IMHO no end user will understand the term **octet**.

**Update**

Seriously, **YOU** had to ask here what this "part" is called (and I consider you to be the technical skilled person here, who wrote the application). Nobody of your users will understand the term **octet** ;)

Answer (score -1):

The closest term I can think of is "subnet," although for the purposes of validation, I would use "octet" for clarity, since subnet is more or less ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, when I hear subnet, I think of 255.255.255.0, not of a part of an IP address.